# Need to update referenced value in generic method - how to make it cleaner?

Tags: c#, .net, code-cleanup

- I have to update ~30 parameters.
- Update depends on `LastUpdated` field.
- Every parameter has it's own `LastUpdated` field.
- This is an ETL process for IoT Device Twin (it means that I cannot change the input JSON), so I'd like to make it as fast as possible (without unnecessary parsings).

Here is the generic method:

```cs
 private static (T value, DateTime? lastUpdate) UpdateSourceIfNewer<T>(T sourceValue, DateTime? sourceLastUpdate, T inputValue, DateTime? inputLastUpdate)
 {
     if (inputValue != null &&
        (sourceLastUpdate is null || sourceLastUpdate < inputLastUpdate))
     {
         sourceValue = inputValue;
         sourceLastUpdate = inputLastUpdate?.LastUpdated;
     }

     return (sourceValue, sourceLastUpdate);
```

But this method requires code which is not very clean for me (below). Still better than a wall of ifs, but is there any way to make it cleaner?

```cs
 (src.Param1, src.Param1LastUpdated) = UpdateSourceIfNewer(
     src.Param1, src.Param1LastUpdated, input.Param1, input.Metadata.Param1);
 (src.Param2, src.Param2LastUpdated) = UpdateSourceIfNewer(
     src.Param2, src.Param2LastUpdated, input.Param2, input.Metadata.Param2);
 /// another ~30 parameters
```

EDIT: ref won't work. When sourceValue is null, the change is not propagated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref):

```
private static void UpdateSourceIfNewer<T>(ref T sourceValue, ref DateTime? sourceLastUpdate, T inputValue, DateTime? inputLastUpdate)
{
    if (inputValue != null &&
       (sourceLastUpdate is null || sourceLastUpdate < inputLastUpdate))
    {
        sourceValue = inputValue;
        sourceLastUpdate = inputLastUpdate;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UpdateSourceIfNewer(ref src.Param1, ref src.Param1LastUpdated, input.Param1, input.Metadata.Param1);
```

**EDIT:** After you said it didn't work, I created a **[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fBnzSk)** which I believe shows that it does work, for all scenarios that I could think of (it always prints that all values are the same).

In doing so I was forced to make a fix to the code because I copied your use of `inputLastUpdate?.LastUpdated`, but because `inputLastUpdate` is of type `DateTime?` I had to remove the `?.LastUpdated` part. Maybe that is related to why you said it didn't work, but I can't figure out why or how.

Comment: ref won't work. When srcValue is null, the change is not propagated. 
Should have write this at the beginning. But thank you!

Comment: Please see my update. If you still think my code doesn't do the same as your code then I would like to see specific examples. Or else improve/extend your sample code so it matches more with your actual program code, and add sample data.